# MySQL WHERE <multiple-column> IN <subquery>

Tags: mysql, where-clause, multiple-tables, in-subquery

Is there a way (without JOIN) to use the `WHERE` clause on 2 columns (OR) `IN` a subquery?
Currently, I'm doing

```
WHERE 'col1' IN
(
    SELECT id FROM table
) OR 'col2' IN
(
    SELECT id FROM table
)
```

And I'm sure I can do better :) . i've also tried `WHERE ('col1', 'col2') IN <subquery>` but MySQL says: `Operand should contain 2 column(s)`

Thanks for your help.

Edit: By "No join", I mean I'm alreeady making many joins: http://pastebin.com/bRfD21W9, and as you can see, the subqueries are on another table.

Comment: why not join? any specific reason?

Comment: This is because I'm already joining a lot. I've updated my original post to add an extract of my current query.

Comment: there are just 3 joins, i don't say there is a lot join.. i suggest you to make one more join instead of making inner query.

Comment: Can you suggest me something? I don't see how to add it, as there is a notion of "OR" instead of "=" :/

Comment: i had eyes on your question, even i was also looking for another way if someone can suggest but.. not found yet.

Comment: you've already suggested something on your post below

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13617/discussion-between-max13-and-manurajhada)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Read you are not agree with `JOIN`, but just another way to do it.. See `join` with `friends` if it is useful to you..

```
SELECT `timeline`.`action`, `timeline`.`data`, `timeline`.`tlupdate`,
            u1.`id` AS ufrom_id, u1.`username` AS ufrom_username, u1.`firstname` AS ufrom_firstname, u1.`lastname` AS ufrom_lastname, u1.`picture` AS ufrom_picture,
            u2.`id` AS uto_id, u2.`username` AS uto_username, u2.`firstname` AS uto_firstname, u2.`lastname` AS uto_lastname, u2.`picture` AS uto_picture,
            m.`id` AS m_id, m.`name` AS m_name, m.`alternative_name` AS m_altname, m.`tiny_img` AS m_tiny, m.`normal_img` AS m_normal
    FROM `timeline`
    JOIN `users` u1 ON u1.`id` = `timeline`.`user_id_from`
    JOIN `users` u2 ON u2.`id` = `timeline`.`user_id_to`
    JOIN `friends` f on f.`idol_id`=u1.`id` or f.`idol_id`=u2.`id`
    JOIN `movies` m ON m.`id` = `timeline`.`movie_id`;
```

### Update:

As you are using `inner join` You can this too to avoid the condition on complete resultSet.

```
JOIN `friends` f on ((f.`idol_id`=u1.`id` or f.`idol_id`=u2.`id`) and f.idol_id = ?)
```

Either you can use `DISTINCT` or use `GROUP BY` to get unique result.

Comment: Closer to what I need. Actually, I'm not so close minded (^^), I wanted to know if it was possible without JOIN. I'm not an SQL master, so thank you for your help. I've added your JOIN and a `WHERE idol_id = ?` to filter them, but I have many times the same rows (12 times, exact same answer) :/ Do you know how to avoid DUPLICATE? (I know the keyword `DISTINCT`, but I think it would be a hack if I use it)

Comment: The data I want is `f.idol_id WHERE f.fan_id = ?`, so I think rewriting `f.idol_id = ?` to `f.fan_id = ?` will be enough ?

Answer (score 35):

```
SELECT *
FROM table

WHERE 
(col_1, col_2) NOT IN
 (SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM table)
```

Answer (score 6):

Rewrite your code like this and you're good to go:

```
WHERE ('col1', 'col2') IN
(
    SELECT id, id FROM table
)
```

Comment: It's closer than what I need. But `('col1', 'col2')` means "AND", and what I need is "OR" ^^'

Answer (score 2):

manurajhada answer is good. If you still decide to avoid the JOIN you could:

```
SELECT ... FROM (SELECT id FROM table) subquery, other_table
WHERE other_table.col1 = subquery.id OR other_table.col2 = subquery.id
```

This should make MySQL use the join buffer to hold the results of the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table1  WHERE (col1, col2) in (select subquerycol1, subquerycol2 from subquery_table where some_condition=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query:

```
select name from user_details where groupid IN ( select g_id from user_groups ) OR  cityid IN ( select c_id from user_cities );
```

Hope this help.

Comment: It could help, but the subqueries are the same. And I need something simplier than your query, which is my current query.

Answer (score 0):

I also face similar problem

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM msg_old WHERE idfrom IN 
    (SELECT olduserid FROM temp_user)
    OR
    idto IN (SELECT olduserid FROM temp_user)
```

I came up with solution

```
SELECT * FROM msg_old 
INNER JOIN temp_user 
ON msg_old.IDFROM = temp_user.olduserid
OR msg_old.IDTO = temp_user.olduserid
```

Comment: The use of `OR` may potentially slowdown the query. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702294/mysql-inner-join-with-or-condition.

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can do. It is easy enough. you must select same number of columns in sub query as you mentioned in the where clause.

Comment: any example would help better !!

Comment: I think, he means @martin-kh query (below)