# MySQL OR condition Not working

Tags: mysql

I want to search a data in to a table

My table structure is Table : tbl_clientinfo_dplist

```
dplist_id    dp_id     dplist
-------------------------------
1             1        aaa
2             1        bbb
3             1        ccc
4             1        ddd
5             2        eee
6             2        fff
7             2        ggg
```

My Another table structure is Table : tbl_client

```
client_id      provider_type     group_name      cmp_legal_name
---------------------------------------------------------------
   1              1                 5                  Test1
   2              2                 6                  Test2
   3              3                 7                  Test3
   4              1                 5                  Test4
   5              4                 6                  Test5
```

dp_id=1 are provider type and dp_id=2 are group name.

how can I search provider type or group name from table?

Here it is my current query

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_client
LEFT JOIN tbl_clientinfo_dplist
     ON (tbl_client.provider_type  = tbl_clientinfo_dplist.dplist_id)
         OR (tbl_client.group_name = tbl_clientinfo_dplist.dplist_id)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702294/mysql-inner-join-with-or-condition

Comment: it's bit confusing as what's your question here?

Comment: Consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements together with a desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, the above can be rewritten as follows, which I think is easier to read...

```
SELECT columns, I, actually, need
  FROM tbl_client c
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbl_clientinfo_dplist l
    ON l.dplist_id IN(c.provider_type,c.group_name)
```

Comment: it returns duplication of rows

Comment: `SELECT columns, I, actually, need
  FROM tbl_client c`, what you mean by  (actually, need). columns for tbl_client fields and I for tbl_clientinfo_dplist